# Extremely slow rendering of Reportviewer in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

I have been looking for a solution for doing reporting in ASP.Net MVC, and I did come across a solution by Rai Kaimal  [Rendering an RDLC directly to the Response stream in ASP.NET MVC](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2009/11/25/rendering-an-rdlc-directly-to-the-response-stream-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx). Everything works just fine, but the localReport.Render() function takes extremely long to render the page (40 seconds for 2 very simple pages - the same reports executes in 2 seconds from a winforms solution). Any help would be appreciated. If there's no way to speeding up the report, I'm interested in knowing how other developers handle the reporting in a ASP.Net MVC solution.

Here is my code:

```
    public ActionResult CustomerReport()
    {
        var localReport = new LocalReport
                              {
                                  ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/CustomerReport.rdlc")
                              };
        var reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource("Customers", _repository.GetAll( ));

        localReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);

        const string reportType = "PDF";

        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension;

        //The DeviceInfo settings should be changed based on the reportType

        //http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155397.aspx

        const string deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo>" +
                                  "  <OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>" +
                                  "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
                                  "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
                                  "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
                                  "  <MarginLeft>1in</MarginLeft>" +
                                  "  <MarginRight>1in</MarginRight>" +
                                  "  <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>" +
                                  "</DeviceInfo>";

        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streams;

        //Render the report
        byte[] renderedBytes = localReport.Render(
            reportType,
            deviceInfo,
            out mimeType,
            out encoding,
            out fileNameExtension,
            out streams,
            out warnings);

        return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);
    }
```

Comment: Note that you are not serving html but PDF and that may take time. Regardless, `LocalReport` is part of ReportViewer control. Try the report using ReportViewer control (web version) - you need to add a aspx page. Try to see how fast report comes in the browser and then how much time it takes if you export it to PDF. If it takes same time then essentially you cannot do much about it.

Comment: My winforms application uses PDF export as well and the rendering takes only 2 secons. But I'll try the the aspx page suggestion.

Comment: I have a similar issue, HTTPwatch shows it to be almost 45 seconds between the request and response. Tracing in the application shows the last segment of my code runs at the 15-16 second mark depending on SQL server load (That is query time + code execution time) then almost 30 seconds to get a server response in which case I can only assume the control is doing something in the background.  It cannot be raw data because a programmatic refresh only takes a fraction of a second, Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Placing `<trust legacyCasModel="true" level="Full"/>` inside `<system.web>` tag in `web.config` did it for me. I'm in ASP.NET Webforms though. [More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23787853/rdlc-localreport-export-to-excel-really-slow#_=_)