# Local report rdlc to pdf very slow

Tags: c#, rdlc

Is there any way to improve the performace of local report or even an alternative if not ? Current code for converting rdlc to pdf below. Have been looking for a solution for quite some time but the general consensus seems to be that its just slow,  Thanks for any help.

```
  public byte[] genReportBytes(int id, string fromm, string too, string           filetype)
{
    reportDetails repD = new reportDetails();
    repD = getOneReport(id);

    LocalReport report = new LocalReport();

    if (fromm != null)
        repD.ParametersCommandLine = "@startdate=" + fromm;

    if (too != null)
        repD.ParametersCommandLine += " @enddate=" + too;

    string RDLCPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RDLCPath"];
    string ReportOutputPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportOutputPath"];

    string RDLCName = repD.RDLCName;
    RDLCPath += @"\" + RDLCName;
    report.ReportPath = RDLCPath;

    string sqlGet = repD.SQLOfReport;

    report.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(repD.DatasetName, getReportData(sqlGet, repD.ParametersCommandLine)));

    // export to byte array

    Warning[] warnings;
    string[] streamids;
    string mimeType;
    string encoding;
    string filenameExtension;
    string deviceInf = "";
    byte[] bytes;
    string extension;

    if (filetype == "pdf")
    {
        deviceInf = "<DeviceInfo><PageHeight>8.5in</PageHeight><PageWidth>11in</PageWidth><MarginLeft>0in</MarginLeft><MarginRight>0in</MarginRight></DeviceInfo>";
        //fileName = ReportOutputPath + @"\" + repD.NameOfOutputPDF + ".PDF";
        bytes = report.Render("pdf", deviceInf, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,
        out streamids, out warnings);
    }
    else
    {
        //fileName = ReportOutputPath + @"\" + repD.NameOfOutputPDF + ".XLS";
        bytes = report.Render(
              "Excel", null, out mimeType, out encoding,
               out extension,
              out streamids, out warnings);
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Those two `ParametersCommandLine` lines make me suspect that your code might be vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql.html). What does your `getReportData` method look like?

Comment: If you use ***.NET 4.5 in ASP.NET*** based application without heavy use of _dynamic types for serialization and deserialization_.  Maybe could use  `<trust legacyCasModel="true" level="Full"/>`

Comment: @Kiquenet Code review stands for reviewing working code, also performance improvements could be asked for. Nice example of this : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104879/creating-a-numeric-phone-keypad/104882#104882

Comment: @chillworld good,  **performance improvements** not same ***performance issues*** ?

Comment: Adrian Nichols has a helper code in

***https://github.com/AdrianNichols/ssrs-non-native-functions/blob/17ee83c9988acc638eb11f961caf0b2a6b77b555/SSRS_Demo/Business/reportHelper.cs***

`Keys`: ***`RenderReportToMemoryAsPDFInAnotherAppDomain`*** Method and ***`ReportHelperInAppDomain`***  class

Answer (score 8):

I've post an answer here [slow-performance-with-dynamic-grouping-and-reportviewer-in-local-mode](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6d89e2ce-3528-465f-9740-7e22aa7b7aae/slow-performance-with-dynamic-grouping-and-reportviewer-in-local-mode?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Basically you have to run the reportviewer in a separated Appdomain, this is the Render method, it takes all the parameters from your current reportviewer control.

```
private static byte[] Render(string reportRenderFormat, string deviceInfo, string DisplayName, string ReportPath, bool Visible, ReportDataSourceCollection DataSources, string repMainContent, List<string[]> repSubContent, ReportParameter[] reportParam)
{
    AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup { ApplicationBase = Environment.CurrentDirectory, LoaderOptimization = LoaderOptimization.MultiDomainHost };
    setup.SetCompatibilitySwitches(new[] { "NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy" });
    AppDomain _casPolicyEnabledDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Full Trust", null, setup);
    try
    {
        WebReportviewer.FullTrustReportviewer rvNextgenReport2 = (WebReportviewer.FullTrustReportviewer)_casPolicyEnabledDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(typeof(WebReportviewer.FullTrustReportviewer).Assembly.CodeBase, typeof(WebReportviewer.FullTrustReportviewer).FullName);
        rvNextgenReport2.Initialize(DisplayName, ReportPath, Visible, reportParam, reportRenderFormat, deviceInfo, repMainContent, repSubContent);

        foreach (ReportDataSource _ReportDataSource in DataSources)
        {
            rvNextgenReport2.AddDataSources(_ReportDataSource.Name, (DataTable)_ReportDataSource.Value);
        }

        return rvNextgenReport2.Render(reportRenderFormat, deviceInfo);
    }
    finally
    {
        AppDomain.Unload(_casPolicyEnabledDomain);
    }
}
```

this is the new Assembly that will run the report:

```
namespace WebReportviewer
{
    [Serializable]
    public class FullTrustReportviewer : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        private ReportViewer FullTrust;        
        public FullTrustReportviewer() 
        {
            FullTrust = new ReportViewer();
            FullTrust.ShowExportControls = false;
            FullTrust.ShowPrintButton = true;
            FullTrust.ShowZoomControl = true;
            FullTrust.SizeToReportContent = false;
            FullTrust.ShowReportBody = true;
            FullTrust.ShowDocumentMapButton = false;
            FullTrust.ShowFindControls = true;
           FullTrust.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += LocalReport_SubreportProcessing;               
        }

        public void Initialize(string DisplayName, string ReportPath, bool Visible, ReportParameter[] reportParam, string reportRenderFormat, string deviceInfo, string repMainContent, List<string[]> repSubContent)
        {
            FullTrust.LocalReport.DisplayName = DisplayName;
            FullTrust.LocalReport.ReportPath = ReportPath;
            FullTrust.Visible = Visible;
            FullTrust.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(new StringReader(repMainContent)); 
            FullTrust.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParam);

            repSubContent.ForEach(x =>
            {
                FullTrust.LocalReport.LoadSubreportDefinition(x[0], new StringReader(x[1]));
            });
            FullTrust.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        }       

        public byte[] Render(string reportRenderFormat, string deviceInfo)
        {
            return FullTrust.LocalReport.Render(reportRenderFormat, deviceInfo);
        }
        public void AddDataSources(string p, DataTable datatable)
        {
            FullTrust.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(p, datatable));
        }

        public SubreportProcessingEventHandler SubreportProcessing { get; set; }

        public static void LocalReport_SubreportProcessing(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
        {
            LocalReport lr = (LocalReport)sender;

            e.DataSources.Clear();
            ReportDataSource rds;

            if (e.ReportPath.Contains("DataTable2"))
            {
                DataTable dt = (DataTable)lr.DataSources["DataTable2"].Value;
                DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
                dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Id={0}", e.Parameters["Id"].Values[0]);
                rds = new ReportDataSource("DataTable2", dv.ToTable());
                e.DataSources.Add(rds);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Doing it this way will require the minimum changes to your current code.
regards.

Comment: Hi. I get: "Object must implement IConvertible." in "The argument type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter[]' cannot be converted into parameter type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter[]".

Comment: sorry @zchpit This solutions is for WebForms, I haven't tested it on WinForms.

Comment: <trust legacyCasModel="true" level="Full"/> worked for me, but I am unsure how to use your code example. What do I do with with the byte array being returned? How do I get a Web Forms page to render it?

Comment: @andrej351 you do the same as with your report, this method takes the same parameters as your reportviewer: 
reportBytes = genReport.LocalReport.Render("PDF"); //replace here by  the method above
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("inline; filename='{0}'", genReport.LocalReport.DisplayName));
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", reportBytes.Length.ToString());
Response.BinaryWrite(reportBytes);

Comment: @montelof Thank you, that sounds like it would work for rendering a PDF to the response. However I have a Web Forms page (including nav, server controls for report params, etc), a Report Viewer server control in the ASPX markup which renders a local report. Do you know if this is this possible?

Comment: instead of render you can use RenderControl, then send the stream to the response, replace the render to something like this:
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
        ReportViewer1.RenderControl(htw);
.....
Response,Write(htw)

Comment: @montelof I'm getting the same error as zchpit, but for the WebForms ReportParameter. 'The argument type Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[]' cannot be converted into parameter type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[]', any ideas what causes this?

Comment: maybe is the wrong report viewer control version im using version 12 you can download from here:https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747

Answer (score 0):

Also, placing `<trust legacyCasModel="true" level="Full"/>` inside `<system.web>` tag in `web.config` will produce the same result. [More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23787853/rdlc-localreport-export-to-excel-really-slow#_=_)